Explicit backing field not working in latest kotlin 2.0.0 android
I am using Kotlin 2.0.0. I was trying in my current android project. I was trying from this video.
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    val state: StateFlow<Int>
        field = MutableStateFlow(0)


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            AndroidTheme {
                SignInScreenRoute()
            }
        }
    }
}

It giving me error
Explicit backing field declarations are not supported in FE 1.0

libs.versions.toml
[versions]
androidGradlePlugin = "8.4.1"
kotlin = "2.0.0"
coreKtx = "1.13.1"
junit = "4.13.2"
junitVersion = "1.1.5"
espressoCore = "3.5.1"
lifecycleRuntimeKtx = "2.8.0"
activityCompose = "1.9.0"
composeBom = "2024.05.00"
navigationCompose = "2.7.7"
koinAndroid = "3.5.6"
koinAndroidxCompose = "3.5.6"
ktor = "2.3.10"
appcompat = "1.6.1"
material = "1.12.0"
serialization = "1.6.3"
googleFont = "1.6.7"

[libraries]
androidx-core-ktx = { group = "androidx.core", name = "core-ktx", version.ref = "coreKtx" }
junit = { group = "junit", name = "junit", version.ref = "junit" }
androidx-junit = { group = "androidx.test.ext", name = "junit", version.ref = "junitVersion" }
androidx-espresso-core = { group = "androidx.test.espresso", name = "espresso-core", version.ref = "espressoCore" }
androidx-lifecycle-runtime-ktx = { group = "androidx.lifecycle", name = "lifecycle-runtime-ktx", version.ref = "lifecycleRuntimeKtx" }
androidx-activity-compose = { group = "androidx.activity", name = "activity-compose", version.ref = "activityCompose" }
androidx-compose-bom = { group = "androidx.compose", name = "compose-bom", version.ref = "composeBom" }
androidx-ui = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui" }
androidx-foundation = { group = "androidx.compose.foundation", name = "foundation" }
androidx-foundation-layout = { group = "androidx.compose.foundation", name = "foundation-layout" }
androidx-runtime = { group = "androidx.compose.runtime", name = "runtime" }
androidx-lifecycle-viewmodel-compose = { group = "androidx.lifecycle", name = "lifecycle-viewmodel-compose" }
androidx-navigation = { group = "androidx.navigation", name = "navigation-compose", version.ref = "navigationCompose" }
androidx-ui-graphics = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-graphics" }
androidx-ui-tooling = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-tooling" }
androidx-ui-tooling-preview = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-tooling-preview" }
androidx-ui-test-manifest = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-test-manifest" }
androidx-ui-test-junit4 = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-test-junit4" }
androidx-material3 = { group = "androidx.compose.material3", name = "material3" }
androidx-material_icons = { group = "androidx.compose.material", name = "material-icons-extended" }
koin-android = { group = "io.insert-koin", name = "koin-android", version.ref = "koinAndroid" }
koin-androidx-compose = { group = "io.insert-koin", name = "koin-androidx-compose", version.ref = "koinAndroidxCompose" }
ktor-client-okhttp = { group = "io.ktor", name = "ktor-client-okhttp", version.ref = "ktor" }
ktor-client-logging = { group = "io.ktor", name = "ktor-client-logging", version.ref = "ktor" }
ktor-client-content-negotiation = { group = "io.ktor", name = "ktor-client-content-negotiation", version.ref = "ktor" }
ktor-client-core = { group = "io.ktor", name = "ktor-client-core", version.ref = "ktor" }
ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json = { group = "io.ktor", name = "ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json", version.ref = "ktor" }
androidx-appcompat = { group = "androidx.appcompat", name = "appcompat", version.ref = "appcompat" }
material = { group = "com.google.android.material", name = "material", version.ref = "material" }
serialization-json = { group = "org.jetbrains.kotlinx", name = "kotlinx-serialization-json", version.ref = "serialization" }
google-font= { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-text-google-fonts", version.ref = "googleFont" }

[plugins]
androidApplication = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "androidGradlePlugin" }
jetbrainsKotlinAndroid = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android", version.ref = "kotlin" }
androidLibrary = { id = "com.android.library", version.ref = "androidGradlePlugin" }
serialization = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization", version. ref = "kotlin" }
compose-compiler = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.compose", version.ref = "kotlin" }

build.gradle.kts(:app)
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsKotlinAndroid)
    alias(libs.plugins.compose.compiler)
}

android {
    namespace = "com.hub.abc"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.hub.abc"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation(project(":network"))
    implementation(project(":core:coroutines"))
    implementation(project(":core:ui"))
    implementation(project(":feature:signup:ui"))
    implementation(project(":feature:signup:data"))

    implementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui)
    implementation(libs.androidx.foundation)
    implementation(libs.androidx.foundation.layout)
    implementation(libs.androidx.runtime)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose)
    implementation(libs.androidx.navigation)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.graphics)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling.preview)
    implementation(libs.androidx.material3)
    implementation(libs.koin.android)
    implementation(libs.koin.androidx.compose)

    implementation(libs.serialization.json)

    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
    androidTestImplementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.junit4)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.manifest)
}


After migrating to Kotlin 2.0 and upgrading Android Studio to Ladybug+:

Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Kotlin: Check the "Enable K2 Kotlin Mode"
Android Studio settings
You can now use Kotlin 2 features, but for some features like explicit backing fields, you need to add this to the Android project's Gradle file.

Warning for explicit backing fields
kotlin {
    //...
    sourceSets.all {
        languageSettings.enableLanguageFeature("ExplicitBackingFields")
    }
    //...
}


How do I update the MutableStateFlow now? I'm getting this error when calling state.update { ... }:
Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of a receiver type mismatch:
fun  MutableStateFlow.update(function: (T) -> T): Unit

Nevermind. I found that my error was not explicitly stating the backing field type:
    field : MutableStateFlow<StateClass> = MutableStateFlow(StateClass())```

This feature is still experimental and needs to be explicitly activated. Add this to your gradle file:
kotlin {
    sourceSets.all {
        languageSettings.enableLanguageFeature("ExplicitBackingFields")
    }
}

Now it should work.
In the case of MutableStateFlow it was a bit wonky for me: Initially I had to explicitly use the fully qualified function name for the backing field, although I did import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.MutableStateFlow:
val state: StateFlow<Int>
    field = kotlinx.coroutines.flow.MutableStateFlow(0)

That went away after some time, though: I have no clue what changed, but now it works as one expects, just with field = MutableStateFlow(0) and I cannot reproduce the initial problem I had anymore.
What I still didn't get to work was the combined usage with an initializer, like this:
val state: StateFlow<Int> = field.asStateFlow()
    field = MutableStateFlow(0)

This doesn't seem to be available in 2.0.0, not even as an experimental feature.
As a closing note: Keep in mind that all of this only works with the new K2 compiler. That will be used for compiling your code when you run a gradle build, but by default it isn't used by your IDE for syntax highlighting, code completion and such. That's also the reason why the code will be highlighted as an error, even when it will successfully compile when the experimetal flag is set. If you want to also use K2 for your IDE follow these steps: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew20.html#support-in-ides
